# Animated Collapse of Webpage Sections

Tags: javascript, html

I've just started with JavaScript, and I would like to implement an animated collapse of certain sections of the page.

Across the top of my page I have a nav bar that contains links to all of the sections of the page. What I want to happen when I click one is:

1. The currently displayed section collapses to nothing
2. The requested section expands (ideally simultaneously) to fill the remaining space
3. The URL to change reflecting this new selection

I want number three so that it elegantly downgrades if JavaScript is not installed, and so that if someone opens it in a new tab it still works.

So how would I go about implementing this? Is this possible/sensible to do with just JavaScript? Or do I really need to go about learning PHP? (I know ASP.NET, but don't have it on my server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is feasible/doable. To implement this, I would probably should use Jquery+AJAX. Just override the link redirects in the navbar to use AJAX. The animations can be done using JQuery or some other library. The [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) looks good.

For updating the URL bar, you can use [window.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) and other associated methods. Keep in mind some old versions of IE [don't](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate) support pushState, so it might be better to disable Javascript for them.

Comment: It's taken me a long time to actually find the time to go about implementing this, but it turned out to be considerably easier than I thought, though it doesn't work very elegantly in IE. Thanks for your help!